# Is there a problem with using deprecated os.popen?

Tags: python, python-3

I'm using `os.popen()` to run terminal commands in multiple projects.

I keep reading that `os.popen()` is deprecated though and I should use `Popen()` instead, but I haven't been able to get `Popen()` to work for me (it freezes the pi for some reason so I can move the mouse but I can't click or type or open the terminal to shut down safely) and its more code and it seems like a lot of trouble to change code that works perfectly fine.

Is there a reason I should actually work harder to stop using `os.popen()` on my pi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [docs.python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen) `os.popen()` is stacked on top of `subprocess.Popen()` - at least for Python 3.x:

> This is implemented using subprocess.Popen; see that class’s documentation for more powerful ways to manage and communicate with subprocesses.

So other than losing some of the more finegrained controls the underlying `subprocess.Popen()` provides there is nothing fundamentally wrong with using `os.popen()`. Since it uses `subprocess.Popen()` I will assume that the safety & reliability issues reported for Python 2.x are not an issue here.

With [Python 2.x](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.popen) however the use of `os.popen()` is not recommended.

> Deprecated since version 2.6: This function is obsolete. Use the subprocess module. Check especially the Replacing Older Functions with the subprocess Module section.

See more: [Python: when should I use subprocess.Popen instead of os.popen?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41678241/3984613)

Comment: So if i'm using Python3 I should just not use it?

Comment: @StarSweeper to my understanding it is ok to use it with Python3.